# Shows UIAlert once in the App

Tags: swift, boolean, uialertview

I would like to show a UIAlert once in the App so i have tried with a Bool typ showones. So i set it false in viewdidLoad and then it´s shows the Alert when i tap on Done in the Alert it´s save the Date and set the showones true. So it comes never but when i stop the Prozess and goes new in the App it´s load the ViewController new and then showones is afresh false. So have anyone an idea i can show it once in the App. 
Thanks for your Help.

```
  var showones: Bool?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        showones = false
    }

      if showones == false {
         let AlertView = DateAlertController(nibName: "DateAlertController", bundle: nil)

         let AlertDateView = SimpleAlert.Controller(view: AlertView.view, style: .Alert)
         showAlert(AlertDateView)                   
         let date = AlertView.DatePicker.date
         PAlertdate = date
    }

        alert.addAction(SimpleAlert.Action(title: "Done", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            if self.Segmentedevery.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                let newDateEvery = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Everyday", inManagedObjectContext: self.mgdContext) as! Everyday
                newDateEvery.picturedate = self.PAlertdate
                newDateEvery.psetremind = true
                self.showones = true   
 }
```

Comment: You need to save the state of the `Bool` for example in `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: How i can make that have you a code sample ?

Answer (score 0):

use NSUserDefaults to save BOOL state is a good idea.

```
if self.canShowAlert() {
    //your code ...

    //set bool state to be false in userDefaults
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "alert")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}

func canShowAlert()-> Bool {
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var canShow: Bool = false
    if let _ = userDefaults.objectForKey("alert") 
        canShow = userDefaults.boolForKey("alert")
    } else {
        userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "alert")
        canShow = true
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
    return canShow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift Code:

```
func canShowAlert() -> Bool {
    var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    showones = false
    if (userDefaults.objectForKey("Alert")) != nil {
        userDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "Alert")

    }
    else {
         userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "Alert")
        showones = true
    }
    userDefaults.synchronize()
    return showones!
}
```

Comment: But when i stop the App and Run once Again it comes the Alert afresh. So when the Prozess is stopped and i click on the app it´s comes afresh. So i need a func as The assent for the UserNotification or the Camera or the PhotoLibrary so the Alert it comes once and then never again.